# Is it posible to open link in Safari from Opera Mini?

Tags: safari, opera, opera-mini

I want to offer user's of Opera Mini open site in native Safari browser on iPhone. How can I open link in Safari from Opera Mini?

Comment: I'd imagine that if this were possible, it would open up a lot of doors for people to abuse it in order to do... malicious things. I don't believe this functionality exists (and for good reason!).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. But [since Opera Mini 8 for iOS](https://dev.opera.com/blog/opera-mini-8-for-ios/) have **Uncompressed mode**, site will render using `WebView` which use Safari engine. So you can offer to open your site in this mode, just add some text to you site.

You can detect opera mini in **mini mode** javascript using `window` property `operamini`:

```
var isOperaMini = Boolean(window.operamini)
```

So you do something like this:

```
var isOperaMini = Boolean(window.operamini)
if (isOperaMini) {
   alert('Switch your Opera Mini to uncompressed mode');
}
```

P.S.

Opera mini in **Uncompressed mode** can be detected via User-Agent:

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) OPiOS/10.1.1.92212 Mobile/11D257 Safari/9537.53

```
 var isOperaMiniUncompressedMode = navigator.userAgent.test(/OPiOS/)
```